# Google bounce email with error 550-5.7.1 Our system has detected that this message is likely unsolicited mail

Tags: email, gmail, smtp, forwarding

I have a forward configuration in my Exim4 server, when it receives a message to a particular address, it is forwarded to a gmail account.

Exim4 is configured with a valid DKIM and SPF authentication and the Return-path is not modified during the forward process.

This is the error of Gmail refusal while my server is trying to forward the message:

> 550-5.7.1 Our system has detected that this message is likely
> unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this
> message has been blocked. Please visit
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError for more
> information.

This error happened forwarding messages, not all messages fails but just few of them and not from a single address or domain, but from many different senders.
If I ask to send the same message directly to gmail address (without server forward), the message is delivered without any error.

I checked with Google postmaster tools and there are not enought data to display the ip reputation or the spam rate.

I checked the link an followed the guildelines for mail forwarding and I think I'm compliant with these rules:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/175365

I have tested it with and without SRS, unfortunately it doesn't change the error.

**With SRS** the return-path is changed but SPF check is valid

```
Return-Path: <SRS0=Zt37=R5=original.domain=user@mymboxserver.com>
```

**Without SRS** return path is untouched, but SPF is not valid.

Comment: Do you apply SRS?

Comment: You said it's not modified. That document says don't modify the envelope sender. But my experience is gmail actually understands and likes SRS.

Comment: This issues was started two days ago while SRS was enabled. I have disabled it yesterday following the guidelines and the issue is still here.

Comment: Then it's an IP reputation problem. You can have bad reputation without postmaster tools showing anything because of too low volume overall. Make 100% sure that you don't have spamming users/contact forms etc. Then make sure to click the 'no spam' button on every mail that gets flagged and it will heal over time.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the reputation because I can send direct messages from this server to gmail without any problem, the problem happens only forwarding messages.
With and without SRS.

Comment: Unfortunately googles spam filter is a black box. But all spam filters work with giving points to various aspects, and summing them up. The forwarding process will add a certain score to that. So, messages which otherwise are perfet (zero score) will pass, but messages which have other potentially suspicious elements will get blocked because the total score will go beyond the trigger value. But there's no sure way to find out.

Comment: What you could try though is, and I'm copying from the googles guidelines you linked: "You can use third-party software to identify spam message and prevent them from being forwarded. If you never forward spam to Gmail, you can change the envelope sender to your domain."

Comment: Did you: (1) Set up valid reverse DNS records for your IP addresses, (2) Add your From address in the Gmail Contacts list, (3) Publish a DMARC record for your domain?

Comment: @harrymc yes, mxtoolbox.com doesn't notify any issue and mail-tester gives a 10/10 score to email (directly) sent from my mailserver. I have a PRT and DMARC record, "From" address are not all in my contact list (because it is impossible to guess who will write to me), but I can say this will not solve the issue, messages are refused even if contacts are in contacts list.

Comment: @1NN I understand you point, but what is very strange to me is that the same direct email to gmail account is accepted, but, when the message is forwarded from my custom address to gmail account it is refused. The content is the same, so it cannot be the content. I have tried with and without SRS, the message is refused.
I'm not complainig because the message is delivered to spam folder, but it is refused with smtp 550 error!

Comment: I meant : Is your Exim4 server (that forwards the emails) defined as a Gmail contact? Or how exactly are you forwarding the emails?

Comment: @harrymc interesting question... no, my server is not a gmail contact. But how to set server hostname as "contact" in gmail? I'm forwarding using the exim4 function to handle alias (  driver = redirect).

Comment: I don't know what that exim function does when forwarding, so I cannot comment. Yet, there is something wrong with your server setup, so that Gmail rejects your forwards. Look perhaps at [post1](https://serverfault.com/questions/613227/exim4-reveals-a-mail-alias-when-remote-server-rejects-spam) and [post2](https://serverfault.com/questions/219640/email-forwarding-from-my-domain-to-gmail-fail).

Comment: Is Postfix an option for you? I use it for my own personal email forwarding and I’ve read that Postfix is much better than Exim in various aspects, so I wonder if you might have better luck with that.

Comment: @Joseph I'm a bit worried about restarting all customizations.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give an definite answer, but perhaps a few guidelines.

You wrote that you don't modify the return path when forwarding. However, it would be more relevant to know if you leave the **envelope** intact. The following assumes that you at least don't modify the **envelope sender**.

First, let's look at SPF:

Without special measures, it is understandable that Google treats the messages as spam. SPF works like that (oversimplified):

When a message arrives, the receiving server extracts the **pretended sender domain** from the **envelope** address (pretended because the envelope can easily be faked), then asks the **DNS server** of that domain whether the current communication partner's IP address is authorized to send email in behalf of that domain. If it isn't, it is likely that the message is treated as spam.

This is what happens in your case (without SRS). The original envelope sender domain's DNS server probably does not have your EXIM SMTP server in the list of hosts which may send email on behalf of that domain. You can't do anything about that, unless you control that DNS server.

SRS theoretically can mitigate the problem, but it has its own issues. The main problem is that **every** SMTP server which is involved in transporting the respective messages must handle the respective headers correctly.

You have described that everything was working with SRS turned on, but it suddenly stopped a few days ago. My personal guess is that since an additional SMTP server is involved in transporting your forwarded messages, and that this server doesn't treat SRS correctly. Something bad could even happen *before* your EXIM server receives that messages.

DKIM shouldn't have the problems denoted above as long as you leave the envelope sender address intact.

Now, my first advice would be to send messages to your EXIM server's special, forwarded address from as many different sender domains as possible. It would be very interesting to know whether **all** of the forwarded messages get rejected, or only a few of them. The result could give a hint about where the problem is. You probably would want to enable SRS for this test.

You should also check which authorization the messages already have which **arrive** at your EXIM server to your special address. I have no clue about EXIM, so I can't tell you whether it supports **checking** SPF or DKIM headers. But what I can say for sure is that it wouldn't be the first time that somebody at the **original sender's** site misconfigures DKIM or SPF; in the latter case, SRS won't help of course.

At least in case of SPF, you can check the situation yourself without re-configuring EXIM.

- First, store one of the problematic messages (in addition to or instead of forwarding it). In the headers of that message, you can identify the IP address of the SMTP server which has delivered the message to your EXIM server. For clarification: If the message ran through multiple SMTP servers, there would be multiple `Received:` header lines; you need the one which designates the **last** SMTP server which directly connected to your EXIM server when delivering the message. Write down the IP address of that server.
- Next, identify the **envelope** sender domain. That may be a bit hard because SMTP servers usually do not add the envelope data to the headers (again, no clue about EXIM). That is, email client software can't show that data. But it should be in the logs. You really need to get the sender's domain from the envelope data, not the normal message headers.
- Next, use software like `host` or `dig` (or eventually some online service) to examine the DNS SPF entries of the envelope sender's domain. Check if the IP address from step 1 is in the list of allowed servers.

The next thing you could test is to turn off SPF and DKIM at all and to filter out the respective headers before forwarding the message. After all, it may be better to not authenticate a message at all than to authenticate it in a way that makes the receiver think that it has been tampered with. Of course, this is only for testing to gain further insight.

Finally, violating the precondition from the second paragraph, you could purposely change the **envelope sender** (replacing the envelope sender by your own email address with a domain part whose DNS entries are under your control) and turn off SRS. That way, when forwarding the message, the receiving server would consult **your** DNS server for the SPF checks. If you have set it up correctly, no more problems with SPF should arise. In this case, you should filter out headers which designate the original envelope sender (as stated above, it is usually not in the headers anyway, but I only know sendmail, so your mileage may vary).

However, when changing the envelope sender, you'll have problems with DKIM, so you should remove the DKIM headers in this case.

Happy testing, and good luck.

P.S. I'll eventually update the answer and give further hints (if I am able to) when you give test results or explain more precisely whether or not you change the envelope.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, i'll proceed with suggested tests. Just a clarification, do you confirm SRS will change envelop-sender (return-path header) to be compliant with SPF? Is it possiible to have both DKIM and SPF validated while forwarding a message?
My doubt is: DKIM signed the original message, SPF validate the original sender, how can I validate SPF if I cannot touch email content?

Comment: Yes, one of the main goals with SRS is to make redirected messages pass the SPF tests. In other words, the envelope sender / MAIL FROM is rewritten so that the envelope sender domain now is yours (enabling you to SPF-authorize the message), but keeping the original sender so that bounces can be delivered back correctly (i.e. to the original sender / return path).  But it works only if *all* SMTP servers involved support SRS correctly.

Comment: Regarding DKIM: You *can* alter a message's headers without breaking the signature, because you (as sender) can configure which parts of the message will be protected by the signature; see `man opendkim.conf`. It heavily depends on the sender's and receiver's DKIM configuration whether forwarding with DKIM will succeed. For example, the sender may have exempted some headers from the signature for certain reasons, but the receiver may insist that those headers must be included. Then the message gets rejected by the receiver although the signature is technically correct.